# How to solve gcc [-Werror=format-security] in function call?

Tags: linux, gcc, zeromq

I have this call to the [czmq](http://api.zeromq.org/czmq3-0:zsock) api:

```
int rc = zsock_connect(updates, ("inproc://" + uuidStr).c_str());
(Note: uuidStr is of type std::string and zsock_connect expects a const char* as its second argument)
```

Which gives compiler error:

```
error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
int rc = zsock_connect(updates, ("inproc://" + uuidStr).c_str());
                                                               ^
```

I've tried:

```
const char* connectTo = ("inproc://" + uuidStr).c_str();
int rc = zsock_connect(updates, connectTo);
```

and also

```
int rc = zsock_connect(updates, (const char*)("inproc://" + 
uuidStr).c_str());
```

But the error persists.

How do I correct this?

Context; I'm trying to compile this code as a Python extension on Linux using pip install.  On Windows it compiles with pip install and runs just fine, presumably that compiler is more permissive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function acts like `printf()` and friends, right? If so, you have the same problem with that that exists with `printf(some_var)` - if the string you're passing has format sequences in it, you get undefined behavior and bad stuff happening because there aren't the arguments present that you're telling the function to expect. The fix is to do something like:

```
int rc = zsock_connnect(updates, "inproc://%s", uuidStr.c_str());
```

Basically, give it a format that takes your string as an argument.